# smoother canvas noise transition - fade in of particles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

Here is my canvas on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vzrandom/fkho6grf/8/

I'm using simplex-noise.js and dat.GUI to create movement of particles. There is simulated click on canvas every 5 seconds. On click first animation is coming in background and new animation starts.

My problem is that animation on click starts too abruptly. I would like to have some kind of fade in of particles.

It seems like a simple problem but somehow I can't get it how to make fade in of elements that are inside the canvas - not entire canvas himself.

Entire code is on jsfiddle, here is part that handles the click:

```
function onCanvasClick(e) {
    context.save();
    context.globalAlpha = 1;
    context.fillStyle = Configs.backgroundColor;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    context.restore();

    simplexNoise = new SimplexNoise();
}
```

Comment: Maybe with two canvas, creating a new canvas on click, animating the old canvas to opacity:0, then removing it. But don't know about efficiency.. very fun animation to play with!

Comment: yes I already played with something like that and it's not the feeling I want to get and this canvas is quite heavy as it is, two of them is just too much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render to an offscreen canvas.

Just create a second canvas

```
var canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas2.width = canvas.width;
canvas2.height = canvas.height;
var ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Then for all your drawing calls use the background canvas 2dContext

To do the fade just render that canvas onto the display canvas setting alpha to make it fade.

The function called by requestAnimationFrame is passed a hi resolution time as the first argument. The code below is for the update function. Note that if you are using a polyfill for requestAnimationFrame you should use one that matches the standard.

```
var fadeTime = 1; // one second
var fadeTimeStart = undefined; // when undefined then this indicates start of fade
function update(time){
     // render your particles to offscreen canvas


    if(fadeTimeStart === undefined){ // get the current time as start
        fadeTimeStart = time;
    }

    // get amount of fade
    var fTime = (time - fadeTimeStart) / fadeTime;
    // is it fading
    if(fTime < 1){  // yes
        ctx.globalAlpha = fTime;
        clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clear last rendered scene
        ctx.drawImage(canvas2,0,0);  // draw the offscreen canvas
    }else{
        // you may or may not have to clear the canvas
        ctx.drawImage(canvas2,0,0); // if no fade and assuming canvas is opaque then just draw the canvas onto the display.
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Then in the click event to start a new fade in just set the `fadeTimeStart = undefined` and it will start a new fade in.

Comment: Thank you it makes sense, but I'm struggling to make it work. I'm not so experienced with this. I know it is much to ask, but if you would be so kind to fork it on jsfiddle?

Comment: I will send you a link when the project is finished, it's interesting one

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the effect you want to achieve, but you might get away with clearing the canvas a little on each iteration by filling it with a semi-transparent color in `update` function, instead of clearing it completely on each click.

See my fork here: https://jsfiddle.net/640e32ua/

Main change is changing Configs.backgroundColor to something semi-transparent and adding these two lines to `update`:

```
context.fillStyle = Configs.backgroundColor;
context.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

Comment: thank you, but I need to clear it completely, if is not cleared it becomes too messy very soon